# Plotting only raster cells that fall within boundaries of another raster in R

Tags: raster, r

I've got two rasters, `soil` and `slope`. I want to plot the `slope` raster but only in areas where there is `soil` (i.e. soil is > 0). How can I do this?

This is the `soil` raster:

[image]

This is the `slope` raster:
[image]

EDIT 1: more information about the rasters.

`soil`

```
 > extent(soil)
 class      : Extent 
 xmin       : -180 
 xmax       : 179.9856 
 ymin       : -60 
 ymax       : 89.994 
 > res(soil)
 [1] 0.008333 0.008333
 > origin(soil)
 [1]  0.001133 -0.002400
```

`slope`

```
 > extent(slope)
class      : Extent 
xmin       : -180 
xmax       : 180.0023 
ymin       : -56.00016 
ymax       : 84.00257 
> res(slope)
[1] 0.008333386 0.008333496
> origin(slope)
[1] 0.0011330 0.0009332
```

EDIT 2: information about dimensions

```
 > dim(soil)
 [1] 18000 43200     1

 > dim(slope)
 [1] 16800 43200     1
```

Comment: The two rasters have the same extent. Do you mean you want the slope where the soil raster is not zero? Does zero define your idea of where "soil" isnt?

Comment: Hi! Yes, exactly. I need to create a graph showing slope only in areas where soil is greater than 0.

Comment: a graph or a map?

Comment: A map! Sorry :)

Comment: do the rasters have the same resolution, extent, and origin? Show the summary of each raster if not.

Comment: Thanks! Added as EDIT in the original post

Comment: They have a different `dim` (rows x columns) too it seems. Can you edit that in as well? The extents almost match in longitude but have clear different latitude ranges which complicates things a bit.

Comment: Please see dimensions in EDIT 2 in the post. Thanks so much :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
require(raster)

# make 2 dummy rasters, different extents but same origin and resolution. Values 1:6
slope <- raster(xmn = 0, xmx = 5, ymn = 0, ymx = 5, res = 1)
slope[] <- sample(1:6, ncell(slope), replace = T)

soil <- raster(xmn = 0, xmx = 7, ymn = -1, ymx = 4, res = 1)
soil[] <- sample(1:6, ncell(soil), replace = T)

# create your blank raster to populate. This is only the area both inputs occupy.
r_intersec <- raster(raster::intersect(slope,soil))

# The other 2 rasters should be cropped to the extent of your target raster, to avoid extent errors as mentioned in the comments
croped_slope <- crop(slope,extent(r_intersec))
croped_soil <- crop(soil,extent(r_intersec))

tmp <- croped_slope
tmp[which(croped_soil[] <= 0)] <- NA

par(mfrow=c(1,3))
plot(slope)
plot(soil)
plot(tmp)
```

*raster sample and crop idea from https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/328883/77836

Comment: This will only work if the rasters overlap perfectly, which they don't when you look at the description in the question.

Comment: @Spacedman Yes, sorry. I believe I fixed it.

Comment: Hi @MarujoRe thanks for your help! When I run your code on my R it throws me an error at the step to create blank raster to populate: `unable to find an inherited method for function ‘raster’ for signature ‘"integer"’`. Not sure why?

Comment: Does running `raster::intersect(slope,soil))` solve the issue? This specifies that `intersect` from the raster package is to be used, in case other packages with functions of the same name is masking the one you want to use.

Comment: Yep, works now! Thank you @humperderp